# Setting date format using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am trying to set the date format as (d-m-Y), but error message says as stated below:

> **SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '20-03-2020'**

Below is my Controller validation code

```
   $request->validate([

       'date' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y',    
   ]);
```

I also tried to set the format in my model, which was also futile

```
protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y';
```

How can I set the date_format?

Comment: @TsaiKoga can't it be set to 'm-d-Y'

Comment: @TsaiKoga, i got this message The date does not match the format d-m-Y

Comment: yes, i am getting  "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value"

Comment: MySQL's default date format is `Y-m-d`, you try to add `d-m-Y`, that's what this error is trying to tell you. Change the format back to `Y-m-d` when you insert data in your database

Comment: I have check the source code, `DateTime::createFromFormat('!d-m-Y', "20-03-2020")->format('d-m-Y') == "20-03-2020";` return true. So the validation is passed. I think kerbholz is right. You need to post your table column's type.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, setting `$dateFormat` on your model "determines how date attributes are stored in the database." Setting it to a value that conflicts with your database's date format will of course lead to the SQL errors you're seeing. So leave it alone.

Adding the property to [the `$dates` array](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) will ensure it's automatically converted to a Carbon object when set, and correctly formatted when saved:

```php
protected $dates = ['myproperty'];
```

This works transparently because Carbon accepts `d-m-Y` as a format for creating objects.